# Use png8 instead of png24 as RGB height map

Tags: compression, png, mapnik, png-24, png-8

I have a 1 band DEM geotiff, and a formula to convert altitude -> RGB and RGB -> altitude (something like this: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data).

Using the formula (and GDAL/Python), I converted my geotiff to a 3 bands (R, G & B) geotiff, each band having values in the 0-255 range.

Using mapnik / mod_tile, I'm then serving my geotiff as PNG tiles to a web client. Everything is fine if I setup mod_tile to serve the tiles as 24 or 32 bits PNGs. But if I serve them as 8 bits PNGs (to reduce their size), then the decoded values are a bit off (I can't see the difference when looking at the image, but the RGB values are not exactly the same and it thus messes my decoded altitudes).

Am I right expecting to be able to do what I want (retrieving the exact RGB values) with 8 bits PNGs instead of 24/32, or there something I don't understand about 8 bits PNGs (if so, I'll have to dive into mod_tile code, I guess that when we ask 8 bits, it generates 24 or 32 and then compress)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not right in expecting that you can compress any ensemble of 24-bit values losslessly to 8-bit values. If there are more than 256 different 24-bit values in the original, then some of those different values will necessarily map to the same 8-bit value.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, it should be worth diving into mod_tile's code (or search for a replacement) then!

Comment: @Mark Adler How is it lossless if you have multiple different values in the input mapping to the same value in the output? Kind of sounds like the definition of lossy.

Comment: @CoryGross I don't think you read my answer.

Comment: @MarkAdler Indeed. My mistake. Sorry about that. Seems I was more tired than I thought.